Issue with Equation Simplification in C
I'm developing a C program to simplify mathematical equations by removing terms with zero coefficients. However, I'm encountering a specific issue with the output of the first simplified equation.
When running the code with the provided input equations, the first simplified equation is not what I expected. Here is the output from the program:
Original Equation: a + 0b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f
Simplified Equation: a+2d

Original Equation: a + b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f
Simplified Equation: a+b=2d

Original Equation: a + 2b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 2f
Simplified Equation: a+2b=2d+2f

Original Equation: a + 2b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f
Simplified Equation: a+2b=2d

However, I expected the first simplified equation to be:
Original Equation: a + 0b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f
Simplified Equation: a=2d

The logic behind equation simplification involves adding terms to simplifiedEquation as they are encountered in the original equation, while skipping letters and values with zero coefficients. The + and = signs should be added to simplifiedEquation as they are found in the original equation. However, if the last term of the original equation is a 0 followed by a letter, the last + sign should be eliminated.
I appreciate any help in identifying and correcting the issue in my implementation.
Below is the code I'm using:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Function to simplify the equation by removing terms with zero coefficients
void simplifyEquation(const char equation[]) {
    char simplifiedEquation[100]; // Arbitrary size for the resulting string
    int simplifiedPos = 0;
    int len = strlen(equation);
    int termFound = 0; // Flag to indicate if a significant term has been found

    // Traverse the original equation
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (equation[i] == '+' || equation[i] == '=') {
            // If we encounter an operator (+ or =), check the captured term
            if (termFound) {
                // Add the operator to the simplified equation
                simplifiedEquation[simplifiedPos++] = equation[i];
                termFound = 0; // Reset the flag
            }
        } else if (isdigit(equation[i])) {
            // Check if the next character is '0'
            if (equation[i] == '0') {
                // Ignore this term (skip to the next space or operator)
                while (i < len && (equation[i] != ' ' && equation[i] != '+')) {
                    i++;
                }
                continue; // Move to the next iteration of the loop
            }
            // Build the term while encountering digits
            simplifiedEquation[simplifiedPos++] = equation[i];
            termFound = 1; // Indicate that we found a significant term
        } else if (isalpha(equation[i])) {
            // If we encounter a letter (variable), add it to the simplified equation
            simplifiedEquation[simplifiedPos++] = equation[i];
            termFound = 1; // Indicate that we found a significant term
        }
    }

    // Check if the last character is a '+' sign and remove it if so
    if (simplifiedPos > 0 && simplifiedEquation[simplifiedPos - 1] == '+') {
        simplifiedEquation[simplifiedPos - 1] = '\0'; // Replace the last '+' with null terminator
    } else {
        // Add null terminator to finalize the string
        simplifiedEquation[simplifiedPos] = '\0';
    }

    // Print the simplified equation
    printf("Original Equation: %s\n", equation);
    printf("Simplified Equation: %s\n", simplifiedEquation);
}

int main() {
    // Array of equations
    const char equations[][100] = {
        "a + 0b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f",
        "a + b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f",
        "a + 2b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 2f",
        "a + 2b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f"
    };

    // Process each equation in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(equations) / sizeof(equations[0]); i++) {
        simplifyEquation(equations[i]);
        printf("\n"); // Print a blank line between equations
    }

    return 0;
}


Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

you should process each side of the = separately. So first split the equation at the =, then call your function on each expression.

You are actually going about it the hard way. It is a lot more work, but using an algebraic parser (recursive descent or shunting yard) to build yourself an AST representing your equation. Then you can make very easy passes over it to manipulate it.

@Dúthomhas This is OP's fourth post. OP has been suggested all that you are already, and has also been suggested to break his code into multiple functions. :)

@Harith Ah. I suspect this is just a school assignment, then. (I see I responded to him already about another assignment.)

If you are limiting yourselv to simple linear equations and you are considering two sides in an equation (the parts to the left and right equals sign) you can do two things:

consider the expression tree as two branches (one for the left part and one for the right part of the equal sign)
consider all the right side terms as negative (change their sign)

so your equation
a + 0b = 0c + 2d + 0e + 0f

can be parsed and solved for each equation side, giving:
a = 2d

or, first:
a + 0b - 0c - 2d - 0e - 0f = 0

and then
a - 2d = 0

both solutions are equivalent.
